# Why doesn't app.component.html render?

Tags: angular

I have the following Angular plnkr.co: https://plnkr.co/edit/xA8jU4QYDGxzohNg5NFj?p=preview.

//app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

//app.component.html

```
testing...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The oputput in the browser is:

```
Loading AppComponent content here ...
```

Why doesn't it see the app.component.html file? Or is this some other issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this :

add below line your **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

[plnkr demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/VN1YbWMrMCjpOXl1zwfV?p=preview)

Comment: That works but why is it needed? None of my files have a hyphen in their name.

Comment: schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ] need to be added to each component where you are using custom HTML tags.

Comment: I see. When I use app-root, I can remove CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA.

Comment: Does not work, In my app-root component html, I call 3 component by selector tag, but the app-root html does not render at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your app.component.html contains `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` but there are no child routes defined. This is causing the issue.

In order to fix this, either you need to remove router-outlet from app.component.html or you should define child route config in app.router.ts.

Working Example: https://plnkr.co/edit/wbW1s8PqDtu35GR8HC8D?p=preview

Visit [Angular Guide for routes](https://angular.io/guide/router) to read more about routing config and child routes.

Comment: I don't see app.router.ts. Also, you include route.html, which is not there either. Why not just use app.component.html?

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        
@Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
        title = 'app';
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please write the below code in the index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <base href="/">
        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does changing the selector make any difference? Also, I'm working app.component.html. Not index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here you were missing correct routing implementation several errors are there in console please refer to them.

app.component.html:

```
testing...
<div routeLink="x" routerLinkActive="active">
  Click
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.route.ts:

```
    import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'x',
  templateUrl: './route.html'
})

export class X{

}


const routes1: Routes = [
    {path : '', redirectTo: '/x', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path : 'x', component: X}
  ]

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes1) ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{

}
```

Please find working example very close to your requirement below:
https://plnkr.co/edit/xA8jU4QYDGxzohNg5NFj?p=preview

Comment: I see this in the HTML output: "Loading AppComponent content here ..."

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me, try this one:

**src/app/app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

from this helpful link:
*https://malcoded.com/posts/why-angular-not-works/*