# Angular is not rendering app.component.html page

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and I am trying to create a sample project using Angular4.
I have created project using `ng new MyApp`. When I run command `ng serve -o` it is showing blank page. When checked console it is showing `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in `core.js` file.
I am using `typescript 2.7.2` and `@angular/cli 6.0.8` and `nodejs v8.11.3` .
I have gone through some solutions on internet but none is working.
I have referred the article :

> [Why doesn't app.component.html render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725378/why-doesnt-app-component-html-render?rq=1)

and few other articles but none is working.
Also when I am creating Angular4 application `angular-cli.json` file is not getting created. I have tried adding the `angular-cli.json` file also but no luck.
Can any one please help me on this?
Please let me know if more inputs are required from my side.

Code for Index.html :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ng4Playground</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for app.component.ts :

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Code for app.component.html :

```html
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Package.json :

```js
{
  "name": "ng4-playground",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Polyfills.ts :

```js
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
 import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Comment: Your project setup is bad. First check your global cli version and reply please.

Comment: Had you run npm install ? check you'r nodejs version as well as cli verison. try to install the latest version.

Comment: @Efe I am using cli version 6.0.8

Comment: @Arash I have run npm install and my node version is v8.11.3

Comment: Install the latest version of nodejs.

Comment: Please add your current node.js version. Also can you please try to create a new project to test out it's not went bad the first one?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have tried creating new project and executed it without doing any changes but still same issue I am facing. I am using nodejs v8.11.3.

Comment: Can you please share the error logs and related code.

Comment: can you post package.json file?

Comment: @OmurbekKadyrbekov I have posted the file. Please check.

Comment: @eduPeeth I have only error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in core.js

Comment: Is it IE browser?

Comment: @SandipPatel No. I am using Google Chrome Version 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Everything is auto generated code by angular CLI. when you do ng new myApp are you able to build the app without any errors? Also if you do npm install is it clean build?

Comment: @eduPeeth I am not getting any error at build time. What is clean build can you please let me know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I am aware this error appears in IE because by default polyfills are commented for IE in `polyfills.ts` file. Still you can check for other browsers as well.

Please check [browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) as described by @Antoniossss:

Comment: I have `polyfills.ts` in my project but only two lines available `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` and `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` is there any else I need to uncomment in that file as all other lines are commented.

Comment: thats for other browser, if you have error in IE browser you have to uncomment IE related lines

Comment: Uncomment all and see if that helps.

Comment: @Antoniossss I have uncommented all the lines in polyfills.ts and it is working now. But can you please help me in explaining the reason behind it?

Answer (score 3):

You are using Version 6 of cli, so ng new will create a Angular 6 application. An Angular 6 app doesnn't have a file named angular-cli.json, but a file named angular.json.
If you want to build an Angular 4 app use "ng new [project_name] --ng4"

Comment: I am follwoing [link](https://coursetro.com/courses/12/Learn-Angular-4-from-Scratch?utm_source=in_article&utm_campaign=article&utm_medium=Learn+Angular+4+from+Scra) It says --ng4 is not required.

Comment: @Shardul Thats was totally right, but the link isn't up to date - your link tells that Angular 6 is out now and that you should follow another tutorial. If you where using an older Version of the client, Angular 4 will be installed. But with Angular 6 the cli also updates the version to 6, so that the ecosystem is oin the same major-version

Answer (score 1):

You need to add polyfils

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

should work after that.